# Synchronize rest call Angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs, api

whenever i am iterating for each loop for making rest call, iteration will get finished before getting even first response..... can you please help me in that.

```
var list = [1,2,3];
$scope.fun1 = function(list) {    
  forEach(list,function(value,key)) {
    console.log("Start");
    restCall(url,function(response) {   //each rest request will tack 30sec.
      console.log(response); // response = 'end'
    });
  };
};
```

**getting output:**
Start
Start
Start
end
end
end

**reuired output:**
Start
end
Start
end
Start
end

Comment: Callback and promises are by definition asynchronous.
What do you want to achieve that requires to be synchronous ?

Comment: yes i want that requires to be synchronous only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rest call needs to return a promise you can watch on. Then you need to build a queue and register them synchronously. So you have a variable and chain your single calls. this could look sth like this

```
var list = [1,2,3];
var queue = new Promise(resolve => resolve());
$scope.fun1 = function(list) {
    forEach(list, function(value,key)) {
        console.log("Start");
        queue = queue.then(() => {
            return restCall(url,function(response) {   //each rest request will tack 30sec.
                console.log(response); // response = 'end'
            });
        });
    };
};
```

If you want to continue the queue even if one request fails, you need to add a .catch() to catch the error

Comment: @RaviPatidar you might consider accepting the answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve but in order to get required output I would suggest using recurrsion.

```
function callApi(list){
  if(!list.length){
    return;
  }
  console.log('start');
  restApi(url, function(){
    console.log('end');
    callApi(list.splice(1));
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i want to achieve this without recursion.